# Expresión regular con lista de números del 1 al 31 separado por comas no repetidos

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo una expresión regular que valida que los valores que se ingresen estén entre el 1 y 31 y que los números ingresados estén separados por comas de esta manera:

```
^([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(,([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))*$
```

pero quisiera validar que además no permita números repetidos o duplicados.

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Siendo sincero creo que sería mejor usar otra forma de validar los datos pues el regex que buscas sería bastante complicado y serías suceptible a un ReDOS

Comment: @Eduardo de acuerdo en que es más sencillo validar con código de JavaScript. ReDOS no aplica en este caso, ya que no hay backtracking redundante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Toda tu expresión regular

```
^([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(,([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))*$
```

se puede acortar como (más compleja, pero 1 única repetición):

```
^(?:(?:^|,)([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))+$
```

fijate como `(?:^|,)` verifica para cada grupo que sea el inicio del texto o que empiece con una coma.

Una vez que tenemos esa estructura, tenemos que exigir el texto *no esté seguido por el número que acaba de coincidir en el primer grupo (rodeado de comas o el inicio/fin del texto)*. Es decir, `(?!.*,\1(?:,|$))` que utiliza un *negative lookahead*.

Con eso, tenemos el resultado:

```
/^(?:(?:^|,)([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?!.*,\1(?:,|$)))+$/
```

Probalo:
https://regex101.com/r/ppIvKu/1

Comment: Gracias @Pollo por la explicación, funciona tal y como lo requería.

Comment: De nada @car-onte! Comentario extra, intentando simplificar la respuesta, estoy permitiendo que el texto empiece con una coma sin número. Si querés evitarlo, podés reemplazar `(?:^|,)` por `(?:^|(?!^),)`

Answer (score 1):

Si prefieres no usar regex creo que esta podría ser una buena solución.

Fíjate que en la excelente regex que pusieron como respuesta el número de vueltas incrementa conforme incrementa tu texto de manera muy rápida. Intenté con el String `"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31` y me calculó que es válido en 3700 pasos de regex, ahora si tuvieras que validar un rango más amplio tu programa requeriría mucho más procesamiento por el regex

Si al final le añado un 32 aumentan otros 308 pasos para finalmente detectar que es inválido.

Esta respuesta es porque es importante saber que regex no siempre es la mejor solución a todos los problemas de validación

```js
let res = document.querySelector("#res");

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", ()=> {
  res.innerText = "";
  let arr = document.querySelector("#numbers").value.replace(/\s/g, '').split(",");
  let val = arr.filter((e) => !isNaN(e) && parseFloat(e) >= 1 && parseFloat(e) <= 31);
  val = new Set(val);

  if (val.size !== arr.length)
    res.innerText = "Entrada inválida";
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numbers" />
<button id="btn">Checar</button>

<p id="res"></p>
```

Comment: Habiendo escrito la otra respuesta, 100% de acuerdo con todo lo que menciona Eduardo.

Answer (score -1):

Toda tu expresión regular

`^([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(,([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))*$`

Solución

`^(?:(?:^|,)([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?!.*,\1(?:,|$)))+$`

Implementación

`/^(?:(?:^|,)([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?!.*,\1(?:,|$)))+$/g`

Prueba en regexr

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probar aca: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Encarecidamente: lee [answer]. 1. Es necesario explicar la respuesta, para que sea útil no solo al OP, sino a los demás usuarios que la vean. 2. Podés darle formato al código con el botón que indica `{}`.

Comment: @padaleiana gracias, se corrigió el formato.